# Ubuntu 16.04 Fabric-Composer Quick-Start TypeError: Cannot read property 'fail' of undefined

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Ubuntu 16.04

System Environment

- Node v6.9.5
- NPM  v4.4.4
- Docker v17.03.1-ce
- Docker-compose v1.11.2

Deleted sample-applications, uninstalled composer-cli, reinstalled composer-cli, cleared all docker images, updated pip, updated rest of dependencies, cloned sample-applications cd into directory and ran `nmp install`

This is the error I get:

```
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     composer archive create --sourceName digitalproperty-network --sourceType module --archiveFile digitalPropertyNetwork.bna && composer network deploy --archiveFile digitalPropertyNetwork.bna  -p defaultProfile -i admin -s adminpw && composer network list -n digitalproperty-network -i admin -s adminpw
```

Here is the Log

```html
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/home/goodfaith/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/goodfaith/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'deployNetwork' ]
2 info using npm@4.4.4
3 info using node@v6.9.5
4 verbose run-script [ 'predeployNetwork', 'deployNetwork', 'postdeployNetwork' ]
5 info lifecycle getting-started@1.0.0~predeployNetwork: getting-started@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle getting-started@1.0.0~predeployNetwork: no script for predeployNetwork, continuing
7 info lifecycle getting-started@1.0.0~deployNetwork: getting-started@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle getting-started@1.0.0~deployNetwork: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle getting-started@1.0.0~deployNetwork: PATH: /home/goodfaith/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/goodfaith/sample-applications/packages/getting-started/node_modules/.bin:/home/goodfaith/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/goodfaith/sample-applications/packages/getting-started/node_modules/.bin:/home/goodfaith/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/bin:/home/goodfaith/bin:/home/goodfaith/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
10 verbose lifecycle getting-started@1.0.0~deployNetwork: CWD: /home/goodfaith/sample-applications/packages/getting-started
11 silly lifecycle getting-started@1.0.0~deployNetwork: Args: [ '-c',
11 silly lifecycle   'composer archive create --sourceName digitalproperty-network --sourceType module --archiveFile digitalPropertyNetwork.bna && composer network deploy --archiveFile digitalPropertyNetwork.bna  -p defaultProfile -i admin -s adminpw && composer network list -n digitalproperty-network -i admin -s adminpw' ]
12 silly lifecycle getting-started@1.0.0~deployNetwork: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle getting-started@1.0.0~deployNetwork: Failed to exec deployNetwork script
14 verbose stack Error: getting-started@1.0.0 deployNetwork: `composer archive create --sourceName digitalproperty-network --sourceType module --archiveFile digitalPropertyNetwork.bna && composer network deploy --archiveFile digitalPropertyNetwork.bna  -p defaultProfile -i admin -s adminpw && composer network list -n digitalproperty-network -i admin -s adminpw`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/goodfaith/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:279:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/goodfaith/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid getting-started@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd /home/goodfaith/sample-applications/packages/getting-started
17 verbose Linux 4.4.0-31-generic
18 verbose argv "/home/goodfaith/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/bin/node" "/home/goodfaith/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/bin/npm" "run" "deployNetwork"
19 verbose node v6.9.5
20 verbose npm  v4.4.4
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno 1
23 error getting-started@1.0.0 deployNetwork: `composer archive create --sourceName digitalproperty-network --sourceType module --archiveFile digitalPropertyNetwork.bna && composer network deploy --archiveFile digitalPropertyNetwork.bna  -p defaultProfile -i admin -s adminpw && composer network list -n digitalproperty-network -i admin -s adminpw`
23 error Exit status 1
24 error Failed at the getting-started@1.0.0 deployNetwork script 'composer archive create --sourceName digitalproperty-network --sourceType module --archiveFile digitalPropertyNetwork.bna && composer network deploy --archiveFile digitalPropertyNetwork.bna  -p defaultProfile -i admin -s adminpw && composer network list -n digitalproperty-network -i admin -s adminpw'.
24 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
24 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the getting-started package,
24 error not with npm itself.
24 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
24 error     composer archive create --sourceName digitalproperty-network --sourceType module --archiveFile digitalPropertyNetwork.bna && composer network deploy --archiveFile digitalPropertyNetwork.bna  -p defaultProfile -i admin -s adminpw && composer network list -n digitalproperty-network -i admin -s adminpw
24 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
24 error     npm bugs getting-started
24 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
24 error     npm owner ls getting-started
24 error There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

When running `composer archive create --sourceName digitalproperty-network --sourceType module --archiveFile digitalPropertyNetwork.bna && composer network deploy --archiveFile digitalPropertyNetwork.bna  -p defaultProfile -i admin -s adminpw && composer network list -n digitalproperty-network -i admin -s adminpw`

I get:

```html
Creating Business Network Archive

Node module search path : 
undefined 

Not found in main node_module search path, trying current directory :/home/goodfaith/sample-applications/packages/getting-started/node_modules/digitalproperty-network
Looking for package.json of Business Network Definition in /home/goodfaith/sample-applications/packages/getting-started/node_modules/digitalproperty-network

Found:
Description:Digital Property Network
Name:digitalproperty-network
Identifier:digitalproperty-network@0.0.6

Written Business Network Definition Archive file to digitalPropertyNetwork.bna
Command completed successfully.

Command succeeded


Deploying business network from archive: digitalPropertyNetwork.bna
Business network definition:
 Identifier: digitalproperty-network@0.0.6
 Description: Digital Property Network

TypeError: Cannot read property 'fail' of undefined
Command failed
```

This is all of the node logs, not sure which one .bna file gets deployed to.

```html
goodfaith@goodfaith:~/sample-applications/packages/getting-started$ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
5c9ea989790d        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.0-alpha      "peer node start -..."   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:7056->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7058->7053/tcp   peer1
42a7ea675cd8        hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.0-alpha      "peer node start -..."   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0
afaf2bbdb46c        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.0.0-alpha   "orderer"                6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer0
817b10f94193        hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.0.0-alpha        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-..."   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca_peerOrg1

goodfaith@goodfaith:~/sample-applications/packages/getting-started$ 

2017-04-15 21:52:33.956 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 001 Initializing ledger mgmt
2017-04-15 21:52:33.956 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 002 Initializing ledger provider
2017-04-15 21:52:34.692 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 003 ledger provider Initialized
2017-04-15 21:52:34.692 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 004 ledger mgmt initialized
2017-04-15 21:52:34.693 UTC [eventhub_producer] start -> INFO 005 event processor started
2017-04-15 21:52:34.694 UTC [chaincode] NewChaincodeSupport -> INFO 006 Chaincode support using peerAddress: peer1:7051
2017-04-15 21:52:34.694 UTC [sysccapi] RegisterSysCC -> INFO 007 system chaincode cscc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/cscc) registered
2017-04-15 21:52:34.694 UTC [sysccapi] RegisterSysCC -> INFO 008 system chaincode lccc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lccc) registered
2017-04-15 21:52:34.694 UTC [sysccapi] RegisterSysCC -> INFO 009 system chaincode escc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/escc) registered
2017-04-15 21:52:34.694 UTC [sysccapi] RegisterSysCC -> INFO 00a system chaincode vscc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/vscc) registered
2017-04-15 21:52:34.694 UTC [sysccapi] RegisterSysCC -> INFO 00b system chaincode qscc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/qscc) registered
2017-04-15 21:52:34.695 UTC [gossip/service] func1 -> INFO 00c Initialize gossip with endpoint peer1:7051 and bootstrap set [127.0.0.1:7051]
2017-04-15 21:52:34.695 UTC [msp] DeserializeIdentity -> INFO 00d Obtaining identity
2017-04-15 21:52:34.695 UTC [msp] Validate -> INFO 00e MSP Org1MSP validating identity
2017-04-15 21:52:34.697 UTC [msp] DeserializeIdentity -> INFO 00f Obtaining identity
2017-04-15 21:52:34.698 UTC [msp] Validate -> INFO 010 MSP Org1MSP validating identity
2017-04-15 21:52:34.698 UTC [msp] DeserializeIdentity -> INFO 011 Obtaining identity
2017-04-15 21:52:34.698 UTC [gossip/discovery#peer1:7051] NewDiscoveryService -> INFO 012 Started {peer1:7051 [] [125 58 68 210 143 225 187 103 137 152 206 221 191 200 16 240 149 119 163 246 238 16 27 103 91 198 163 125 200 174 34 56] peer1:7051} incTime is 1492293154698594806
2017-04-15 21:52:34.698 UTC [gossip/gossip#peer1:7051] NewGossipService -> INFO 013 Creating gossip service with self membership of {peer1:7051 [] [125 58 68 210 143 225 187 103 137 152 206 221 191 200 16 240 149 119 163 246 238 16 27 103 91 198 163 125 200 174 34 56] peer1:7051}
2017-04-15 21:52:34.698 UTC [msp] DeserializeIdentity -> INFO 014 Obtaining identity
2017-04-15 21:52:34.698 UTC [msp] Validate -> INFO 015 MSP Org1MSP validating identity
2017-04-15 21:52:34.701 UTC [gossip/discovery#peer1:7051] connect2BootstrapPeers -> INFO 017 Entering: [127.0.0.1:7051]
2017-04-15 21:52:34.701 UTC [gossip/discovery#peer1:7051] connect2BootstrapPeers -> INFO 018 Exiting
2017-04-15 21:52:34.699 UTC [msp] DeserializeIdentity -> INFO 016 Obtaining identity
2017-04-15 21:52:34.701 UTC [msp] Validate -> INFO 019 MSP Org1MSP validating identity
2017-04-15 21:52:34.702 UTC [gossip/gossip#peer1:7051] start -> INFO 01a Gossip instance peer1:7051 started
2017-04-15 21:52:34.704 UTC [chaincode] Init -> INFO 01b Init CSCC
2017-04-15 21:52:34.704 UTC [sysccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 01c system chaincode cscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/cscc) deployed
2017-04-15 21:52:34.705 UTC [sysccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 01d system chaincode lccc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lccc) deployed
2017-04-15 21:52:34.705 UTC [escc] Init -> INFO 01e Successfully initialized ESCC
2017-04-15 21:52:34.705 UTC [sysccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 01f system chaincode escc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/escc) deployed
2017-04-15 21:52:34.706 UTC [sysccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 020 system chaincode vscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/vscc) deployed
2017-04-15 21:52:34.706 UTC [qscc] Init -> INFO 021 Init QSCC
2017-04-15 21:52:34.706 UTC [sysccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 022 system chaincode qscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/qscc) deployed
2017-04-15 21:52:34.706 UTC [nodeCmd] initSysCCs -> INFO 023 Deployed system chaincodess
2017-04-15 21:52:34.707 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 024 Starting peer with ID=[name:"peer1" ], network ID=[dev], address=[peer1:7051]
2017-04-15 21:52:34.815 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 025 Started peer with ID=[name:"peer1" ], network ID=[dev], address=[peer1:7051]
2017-04-15 21:52:41.746 UTC [ledgermgmt] CreateLedger -> INFO 026 Creating ledger with id = mychannel
2017-04-15 21:52:41.861 UTC [ledgermgmt] CreateLedger -> INFO 027 Created ledger with id = mychannel
2017-04-15 21:52:41.917 UTC [kvledger] Commit -> INFO 028 Channel [mychannel]: Created block [0] with 1 transaction(s)
2017-04-15 21:52:41.928 UTC [gossip/state] NewGossipStateProvider -> INFO 029 Updating node metadata information, current ledger sequence is at = 0, next expected block is = 1
2017-04-15 21:52:41.931 UTC [deliveryClient] NewDeliverService -> INFO 02a Creating delivery service to get blocks from the ordering service, orderer0:7050
2017-04-15 21:52:41.962 UTC [chaincode] Init -> INFO 02b Init CSCC
2017-04-15 21:52:41.962 UTC [sysccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 02c system chaincode cscc/mychannel(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/cscc) deployed
2017-04-15 21:52:41.963 UTC [sysccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 02d system chaincode lccc/mychannel(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lccc) deployed
2017-04-15 21:52:41.963 UTC [escc] Init -> INFO 02e Successfully initialized ESCC
2017-04-15 21:52:41.963 UTC [sysccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 02f system chaincode escc/mychannel(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/escc) deployed
2017-04-15 21:52:41.964 UTC [sysccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 030 system chaincode vscc/mychannel(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/vscc) deployed
2017-04-15 21:52:41.964 UTC [qscc] Init -> INFO 031 Init QSCC
2017-04-15 21:52:41.964 UTC [sysccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 032 system chaincode qscc/mychannel(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/qscc) deployed
2017-04-15 21:52:43.705 UTC [gossip/gossip#peer1:7051] func2 -> INFO 033 Learned of a new certificate: [10 7 79 114 103 49 77 83 80 18 244 5 45 45 45 45 45 66 69 71 73 78 32 45 45 45 45 45 10 77 73 73 67 69 106 67 67 65 98 105 103 65 119 73 66 65 103 73 81 80 106 98 54 51 109 68 76 52 101 48 54 50 77 80 106 116 99 65 49 67 68 65 75 66 103 103 113 104 107 106 79 80 81 81 68 65 106 66 103 77 81 115 119 10 67 81 89 68 86 81 81 71 69 119 74 86 85 122 69 84 77 66 69 71 65 49 85 69 67 66 77 75 81 50 70 115 97 87 90 118 99 109 53 112 89 84 69 87 77 66 81 71 65 49 85 69 66 120 77 78 85 50 70 117 73 69 90 121 10 89 87 53 106 97 88 78 106 98 122 69 82 77 65 56 71 65 49 85 69 67 104 77 73 99 71 86 108 99 107 57 121 90 122 69 120 69 84 65 80 66 103 78 86 66 65 77 84 67 72 66 108 90 88 74 80 99 109 99 120 77 66 52 88 10 68 84 69 51 77 68 77 119 77 84 69 51 77 122 89 48 77 86 111 88 68 84 73 51 77 68 73 121 78 122 69 51 77 122 89 48 77 86 111 119 85 106 69 76 77 65 107 71 65 49 85 69 66 104 77 67 86 86 77 120 69 122 65 82 10 66 103 78 86 66 65 103 84 67 107 78 104 98 71 108 109 98 51 74 117 97 87 69 120 70 106 65 85 66 103 78 86 66 65 99 84 68 86 78 104 98 105 66 71 99 109 70 117 89 50 108 122 89 50 56 120 70 106 65 85 66 103 78 86 10 66 65 77 84 68 88 66 108 90 88 74 80 99 109 99 120 85 71 86 108 99 106 69 119 87 84 65 84 66 103 99 113 104 107 106 79 80 81 73 66 66 103 103 113 104 107 106 79 80 81 77 66 66 119 78 67 65 65 83 48 104 79 56 67 10 56 112 104 43 80 105 70 107 89 105 107 100 86 65 75 47 122 67 100 50 99 107 120 98 54 109 53 98 84 79 113 53 52 86 116 87 82 55 119 98 100 80 117 117 57 100 106 73 67 84 97 82 79 84 85 109 102 101 111 65 72 70 54 48 10 111 108 47 90 47 112 101 110 82 47 71 54 99 104 113 75 111 50 73 119 89 68 65 79 66 103 78 86 72 81 56 66 65 102 56 69 66 65 77 67 66 97 65 119 69 119 89 68 86 82 48 108 66 65 119 119 67 103 89 73 75 119 89 66 10 66 81 85 72 65 119 69 119 68 65 89 68 86 82 48 84 65 81 72 47 66 65 73 119 65 68 65 114 66 103 78 86 72 83 77 69 74 68 65 105 103 67 68 89 112 98 80 75 119 98 103 104 57 117 83 48 104 56 54 118 72 57 73 53 10 122 99 47 68 69 73 108 66 85 74 67 76 107 80 66 101 107 88 108 86 97 106 65 75 66 103 103 113 104 107 106 79 80 81 81 68 65 103 78 73 65 68 66 70 65 105 69 65 109 71 83 51 76 84 97 113 67 107 87 86 43 109 121 108 10 108 104 103 57 111 118 116 76 74 65 66 117 120 81 76 110 97 106 77 74 89 81 79 88 85 82 103 67 73 72 76 86 78 114 68 98 69 70 48 75 112 69 109 70 119 88 73 66 89 77 70 100 115 75 71 82 65 70 48 107 67 52 51 77 10 98 112 113 56 55 85 74 113 10 45 45 45 45 45 69 78 68 32 45 45 45 45 45 10]
^C

goodfaith@goodfaith:~/sample-applications/packages/getting-started$ 

2017-04-15 21:52:32.342 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 001 Initializing ledger mgmt
2017-04-15 21:52:32.342 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 002 Initializing ledger provider
2017-04-15 21:52:32.694 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 003 ledger provider Initialized
2017-04-15 21:52:32.695 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 004 ledger mgmt initialized
2017-04-15 21:52:32.696 UTC [eventhub_producer] start -> INFO 005 event processor started
2017-04-15 21:52:32.697 UTC [chaincode] NewChaincodeSupport -> INFO 006 Chaincode support using peerAddress: peer0:7051
2017-04-15 21:52:32.697 UTC [sysccapi] RegisterSysCC -> INFO 007 system chaincode cscc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/cscc) registered
2017-04-15 21:52:32.697 UTC [sysccapi] RegisterSysCC -> INFO 008 system chaincode lccc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lccc) registered
2017-04-15 21:52:32.697 UTC [sysccapi] RegisterSysCC -> INFO 009 system chaincode escc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/escc) registered
2017-04-15 21:52:32.698 UTC [sysccapi] RegisterSysCC -> INFO 00a system chaincode vscc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/vscc) registered
2017-04-15 21:52:32.698 UTC [sysccapi] RegisterSysCC -> INFO 00b system chaincode qscc(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/qscc) registered
2017-04-15 21:52:32.698 UTC [gossip/service] func1 -> INFO 00c Initialize gossip with endpoint peer0:7051 and bootstrap set [127.0.0.1:7051]
2017-04-15 21:52:32.698 UTC [msp] DeserializeIdentity -> INFO 00d Obtaining identity
2017-04-15 21:52:32.699 UTC [msp] Validate -> INFO 00e MSP Org1MSP validating identity
2017-04-15 21:52:32.701 UTC [msp] DeserializeIdentity -> INFO 00f Obtaining identity
2017-04-15 21:52:32.701 UTC [msp] Validate -> INFO 010 MSP Org1MSP validating identity
2017-04-15 21:52:32.701 UTC [msp] DeserializeIdentity -> INFO 011 Obtaining identity
2017-04-15 21:52:32.702 UTC [gossip/discovery#peer0:7051] NewDiscoveryService -> INFO 012 Started {peer0:7051 [] [156 43 33 171 114 249 57 151 235 35 197 207 85 206 60 90 178 209 11 90 101 229 107 30 108 214 245 107 90 240 230 193] peer0:7051} incTime is 1492293152702183828
2017-04-15 21:52:32.703 UTC [gossip/gossip#peer0:7051] NewGossipService -> INFO 013 Creating gossip service with self membership of {peer0:7051 [] [156 43 33 171 114 249 57 151 235 35 197 207 85 206 60 90 178 209 11 90 101 229 107 30 108 214 245 107 90 240 230 193] peer0:7051}
2017-04-15 21:52:32.703 UTC [msp] DeserializeIdentity -> INFO 014 Obtaining identity
2017-04-15 21:52:32.704 UTC [msp] Validate -> INFO 015 MSP Org1MSP validating identity
2017-04-15 21:52:32.704 UTC [msp] DeserializeIdentity -> INFO 016 Obtaining identity
2017-04-15 21:52:32.704 UTC [msp] Validate -> INFO 017 MSP Org1MSP validating identity
2017-04-15 21:52:32.705 UTC [gossip/discovery#peer0:7051] connect2BootstrapPeers -> INFO 018 Entering: [127.0.0.1:7051]
2017-04-15 21:52:32.705 UTC [gossip/discovery#peer0:7051] connect2BootstrapPeers -> INFO 019 Exiting
2017-04-15 21:52:32.705 UTC [gossip/gossip#peer0:7051] start -> INFO 01a Gossip instance peer0:7051 started
2017-04-15 21:52:32.706 UTC [chaincode] Init -> INFO 01b Init CSCC
2017-04-15 21:52:32.706 UTC [sysccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 01c system chaincode cscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/cscc) deployed
2017-04-15 21:52:32.706 UTC [sysccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 01d system chaincode lccc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lccc) deployed
2017-04-15 21:52:32.707 UTC [escc] Init -> INFO 01e Successfully initialized ESCC
2017-04-15 21:52:32.707 UTC [sysccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 01f system chaincode escc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/escc) deployed
2017-04-15 21:52:32.707 UTC [sysccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 020 system chaincode vscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/vscc) deployed
2017-04-15 21:52:32.707 UTC [qscc] Init -> INFO 021 Init QSCC
2017-04-15 21:52:32.707 UTC [sysccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 022 system chaincode qscc/(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/qscc) deployed
2017-04-15 21:52:32.707 UTC [nodeCmd] initSysCCs -> INFO 023 Deployed system chaincodess
2017-04-15 21:52:32.708 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 024 Starting peer with ID=[name:"peer0" ], network ID=[dev], address=[peer0:7051]
2017-04-15 21:52:32.774 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 025 Started peer with ID=[name:"peer0" ], network ID=[dev], address=[peer0:7051]
2017-04-15 21:52:41.746 UTC [ledgermgmt] CreateLedger -> INFO 026 Creating ledger with id = mychannel
2017-04-15 21:52:41.861 UTC [ledgermgmt] CreateLedger -> INFO 027 Created ledger with id = mychannel
2017-04-15 21:52:41.917 UTC [kvledger] Commit -> INFO 028 Channel [mychannel]: Created block [0] with 1 transaction(s)
2017-04-15 21:52:41.934 UTC [gossip/gossip#peer0:7051] JoinChan -> INFO 029 Anchor peer with same endpoint, skipping connecting to myself
2017-04-15 21:52:41.934 UTC [gossip/state] NewGossipStateProvider -> INFO 02a Updating node metadata information, current ledger sequence is at = 0, next expected block is = 1
2017-04-15 21:52:41.934 UTC [deliveryClient] NewDeliverService -> INFO 02b Creating delivery service to get blocks from the ordering service, orderer0:7050
2017-04-15 21:52:41.967 UTC [chaincode] Init -> INFO 02c Init CSCC
2017-04-15 21:52:41.967 UTC [sysccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 02d system chaincode cscc/mychannel(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/cscc) deployed
2017-04-15 21:52:41.967 UTC [sysccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 02e system chaincode lccc/mychannel(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lccc) deployed
2017-04-15 21:52:41.968 UTC [escc] Init -> INFO 02f Successfully initialized ESCC
2017-04-15 21:52:41.969 UTC [sysccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 030 system chaincode escc/mychannel(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/escc) deployed
2017-04-15 21:52:41.969 UTC [sysccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 031 system chaincode vscc/mychannel(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/vscc) deployed
2017-04-15 21:52:41.969 UTC [qscc] Init -> INFO 032 Init QSCC
2017-04-15 21:52:41.969 UTC [sysccapi] deploySysCC -> INFO 033 system chaincode qscc/mychannel(github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/qscc) deployed
2017-04-15 21:52:45.168 UTC [eventhub_producer] Chat -> ERRO 034 Error during Chat, stopping handler: stream error: code = 1 desc = "context canceled"
2017-04-15 21:52:53.714 UTC [gossip/gossip#peer0:7051] func2 -> INFO 035 Learned of a new certificate: [10 7 79 114 103 49 77 83 80 18 244 5 45 45 45 45 45 66 69 71 73 78 32 45 45 45 45 45 10 77 73 73 67 69 106 67 67 65 98 109 103 65 119 73 66 65 103 73 82 65 78 103 100 53 103 119 72 75 120 78 121 113 120 112 116 118 52 48 111 80 69 107 119 67 103 89 73 75 111 90 73 122 106 48 69 65 119 73 119 89 68 69 76 10 77 65 107 71 65 49 85 69 66 104 77 67 86 86 77 120 69 122 65 82 66 103 78 86 66 65 103 84 67 107 78 104 98 71 108 109 98 51 74 117 97 87 69 120 70 106 65 85 66 103 78 86 66 65 99 84 68 86 78 104 98 105 66 71 10 99 109 70 117 89 50 108 122 89 50 56 120 69 84 65 80 66 103 78 86 66 65 111 84 67 72 66 108 90 88 74 80 99 109 99 120 77 82 69 119 68 119 89 68 86 81 81 68 69 119 104 119 90 87 86 121 84 51 74 110 77 84 65 101 10 70 119 48 120 78 122 65 122 77 68 69 120 78 122 77 50 78 68 70 97 70 119 48 121 78 122 65 121 77 106 99 120 78 122 77 50 78 68 70 97 77 70 73 120 67 122 65 74 66 103 78 86 66 65 89 84 65 108 86 84 77 82 77 119 10 69 81 89 68 86 81 81 73 69 119 112 68 89 87 120 112 90 109 57 121 98 109 108 104 77 82 89 119 70 65 89 68 86 81 81 72 69 119 49 84 89 87 52 103 82 110 74 104 98 109 78 112 99 50 78 118 77 82 89 119 70 65 89 68 10 86 81 81 68 69 119 49 119 90 87 86 121 84 51 74 110 77 86 66 108 90 88 73 121 77 70 107 119 69 119 89 72 75 111 90 73 122 106 48 67 65 81 89 73 75 111 90 73 122 106 48 68 65 81 99 68 81 103 65 69 90 105 98 89 10 112 84 117 114 55 104 47 76 73 107 90 107 86 49 121 114 49 49 109 80 48 77 52 72 116 115 43 65 82 114 107 121 51 114 57 55 87 105 104 118 70 48 43 84 103 120 85 73 85 114 70 106 69 101 52 89 118 43 83 73 108 122 53 43 10 73 69 54 66 108 78 101 109 97 70 54 55 110 85 101 68 43 97 78 105 77 71 65 119 68 103 89 68 86 82 48 80 65 81 72 47 66 65 81 68 65 103 87 103 77 66 77 71 65 49 85 100 74 81 81 77 77 65 111 71 67 67 115 71 10 65 81 85 70 66 119 77 66 77 65 119 71 65 49 85 100 69 119 69 66 47 119 81 67 77 65 65 119 75 119 89 68 86 82 48 106 66 67 81 119 73 111 65 103 50 75 87 122 121 115 71 52 73 102 98 107 116 73 102 79 114 120 47 83 10 79 99 51 80 119 120 67 74 81 86 67 81 105 53 68 119 88 112 70 53 86 87 111 119 67 103 89 73 75 111 90 73 122 106 48 69 65 119 73 68 82 119 65 119 82 65 73 103 74 54 122 109 71 84 89 87 101 65 106 97 97 56 122 86 10 73 55 51 116 51 90 111 112 47 109 70 55 57 48 78 119 107 72 50 83 83 108 116 52 83 65 77 67 73 71 57 121 101 72 55 75 56 89 100 68 56 65 111 51 107 66 105 65 82 121 106 73 43 81 112 105 87 113 105 49 75 56 113 83 10 98 54 69 87 112 116 103 50 10 45 45 45 45 45 69 78 68 32 45 45 45 45 45 10]
^C

goodfaith@goodfaith:~/sample-applications/packages/getting-started$ \

2017-04-15 21:52:30.473 UTC [orderer/multichain] NewManagerImpl -> INFO 001 Starting with system channel: testchainid and orderer type solo
2017-04-15 21:52:30.473 UTC [orderer/main] NewServer -> INFO 002 Starting orderer
2017-04-15 21:52:30.473 UTC [orderer/main] main -> INFO 003 Beginning to serve requests
2017-04-15 21:52:35.456 UTC [msp] Validate -> INFO 004 MSP OrdererMSP validating identity
2017-04-15 21:52:35.464 UTC [msp] Validate -> INFO 005 MSP OrdererMSP validating identity
2017-04-15 21:52:35.507 UTC [orderer/multichain] newChain -> INFO 006 Created and starting new chain mychannel
2017-04-15 21:52:41.708 UTC [msp] Validate -> INFO 007 MSP Org1MSP validating identity
2017-04-15 21:52:41.717 UTC [orderer/common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 008 Error reading from stream: EOF
2017-04-15 21:52:41.965 UTC [msp] Validate -> INFO 009 MSP Org1MSP validating identity
^C

goodfaith@goodfaith:~/sample-applications/packages/getting-started$

2017/04/15 21:52:29 [INFO] Created default configuration file at /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
2017/04/15 21:52:29 Initialize BCCSP [SW]
2017/04/15 21:52:29 [INFO] The CA key and certificate files already exist
2017/04/15 21:52:29 [INFO] Key file location: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/d8a5b3cac1b821f6e4b487ceaf1fd239cdcfc310894150908b90f05e9179556a_sk
2017/04/15 21:52:29 [INFO] Certificate file location: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/peerOrg1-cert.pem
2017/04/15 21:52:31 [INFO] Initialized sqlite3 data base at /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server.db
2017/04/15 21:52:31 [INFO] Listening at http://0.0.0.0:7054
```

Comment: It looks like the deploy failed. Can you run `docker ps -a` to check the status of the 3 containers for the Fabric? This looks similar to this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349693/fabric-composer-quick-start-failing-when-trying-to-deploy-the-bna-file-on-osx It could also be the timeout issue described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264985/fabric-composer-quickstart-error

Comment: `hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.0-alpha      "peer node start -..."          Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:7056->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7058->7053/tcp   peer1
hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.0.0-alpha      "peer node start -..."          Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0
hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.0.0-alpha   "sh -c 'fabric-ca-..."       Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp       ca_peerOrg1
hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.0.0-alpha   "orderer"    Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer0` Nodes are up.

Comment: It looks like you have HLF v1 Alpha running. The Quickstart runs against HLF v0.6. You didn't run `npm install` on the QuickStart.

Comment: Does Fabric Composer bypass the Enrollment Certificate Authority building the Business Network Definition? Is there a short explanation of how that works in practice? Also, to follow up with the trouble shooting: I followed the suggested links to resolve my error. Like Bill, netstat -a reported none of the ports defined were in use, this was with HLFv1 nodes, not HLF v0.6 nodes. The error message Bill had at peer node were ECA transport errors. Did not check node logs since ports were not exposed. Also, HLFv1 .sh's are now in the sample-application folder and that's why HLFv1 nodes spun up.

Comment: Edited above to include node logs. Ports are exposed. The .bna file gets created, but still get the same error when deployed to network.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies - the sample-applications repository was incorrectly updated to use Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 when it is not yet ready for prime-time. I've reverted the changes to sample-applications.

Please can you pull down the latest version of the sample-applications repository and try again? You may need to manually remove the Hyperledger Fabric v1.0 containers using the command: `docker ps -aq | xargs docker rm -f`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using v1.0, copyng hlfv1/connection.json to ~/.composer-connection-profiles/defaultProfile/connection.json manually may work.

You may need to update path inside hlfv1/connection.json too.

Looks like the format of connection.json has changed.
There is a instruction [here](https://github.com/fabric-composer/sample-applications-hlfv1/tree/master/packages/getting-started).